# Why Firebase prod project does not show any analytics data in the flutter app

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, firebase-analytics

I have the three android project environments in firebase. The `dev` and `qa` working fine. but the `prod` environment does not display.

[image]

it is a `flutter` android project.
What can I do?

Comment: does DebugVIew shows any data?

Comment: No, the dev and qa working fine.

Comment: I would suggest double checking the [config file](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7015592) you’re using in your app if it matches the one in your Firebase project (Project Overview > Project Setting > General). Firebase uses the App ID in the configuration file to map the analytics data to your Firebase project. Also make sure that the Analytics data collection is not [disabled](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/configure-data-collection?platform=android) in your app.